# Angular PWA / Service worker offline translation width ngx-translate

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, ngx-translate, angular-service-worker

i have an angular pwa app using [@ngx-translate/core](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core) and [@ngx-translate/http-loader](https://github.com/ngx-translate/http-loader) for translations. So I wonder if it's possible to get the translations working if the device is offline.

Is there a way to cache the http-loader requests, maybe in a dataGroup in the ngsw-config.json file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you follow the standard pattern and use json files as your locale information, then you would use asset groups (see below):

```
{
  "name": "translate",
  // Use lazy. You don't want to install unless they use the translation
  "installMode": "lazy", 
  // Use prefetch because you want it to update every time the app updates
  "updateMode": "prefetch",
  "resources": {
    "files": "/assets/i18n/*.json"
  }
}
```

See https://christianlydemann.com/how-to-cache-http-requests-in-an-angular-pwa/ and https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-config

Comment: Thanks for your answer but how to i configurate the get request of the http-loader of the ngx translator?

Comment: After digging in a little more, I would say that it depends. I have updated my answer.

Comment: perfect thanks, that was exact what I was looking for!